# Ubuntu focal cannot resolve local host

Tags: dns

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS and using my router as DNS server

> ```
> $ resolvectl status
> ...
> Link 2 (wlp2s0)
>       Current Scopes: DNS
> DefaultRoute setting: yes
>        LLMNR setting: yes
> MulticastDNS setting: no
>   DNSOverTLS setting: no
>       DNSSEC setting: no
>     DNSSEC supported: no
>   Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
>          DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
> ```

Name resolution works for remote hosts

> ```
> $ nslookup www.google.com
> Server:         127.0.0.53
> Address:        127.0.0.53#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
> Name:   www.google.com
> Address: 142.251.41.4
> Name:   www.google.com
> Address: 2607:f8b0:4006:81f::2004
> ```

but not for hosts in LAN

> ```
> ravi@adyar[~]$ nslookup voyager
> Server:         127.0.0.53
> Address:        127.0.0.53#53
>
> ** server can't find voyager: SERVFAIL
> ```

Comment: This looks like a question about how to use your router's DNS settings.

Comment: A windows client which uses the same router in the LAN, has no such issues with resolution of local hosts. Based on this, I am thinking this must be an issue with focal setup.

Comment: For name resoving you need a complete name (including domain), not only the short name. I guess the "DNS Domain" is missing. This is usually provided via DHCP. But if you configure your DNS server manually, you need to set it manually.